# kivy setting default_font doesn't change font

Tags: kivy

I'm using the following config lines to set the font used by kivy globally:

```
Config.set('graphics', 'default_font', '["Arial", "C:/Windows/Fonts/arial.ttf", "C:/Windows/Fonts/ariali.ttf", "C:/Windows/Fonts/arialbd.ttf", "C:/Windows/Fonts/arialbi.ttf"]')
#or this 
#Config.set('graphics', 'default_font', ["Arial", "C:/Windows/Fonts/arial.ttf", "C:/Windows/Fonts/ariali.ttf", "C:/Windows/Fonts/arialbd.ttf", "C:/Windows/Fonts/arialbi.ttf"])
Config.write()
```

Nothing is changing. Kivy is still using it's default Roboto font. What am I missing here? Any suggestions?

Comment: I believe that the value you are setting should be a `list` not a `string`.

Comment: Try using `Config.set('kivy', 'default_font', . . .`. Strangely, this works for me using Python 3.6 and Kivy 1.11, but your original code (as described in the docs) does not work for me either.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As of kivy 1.10 `default_font` is now in the `kivy` section of `Config` (not mentioned in the docs). It appears that `default_font` still appears in the `graphics` section, but is ignored.